# What is the solution of this quadratic function

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

$$iz^2 − 2 \sqrt{2}z − 2
\sqrt{3} = 0,\qquad z \in \mathbb{C}$$

I'm new to this site, i'm really thankful for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$iz^2-2\sqrt{2}z-2\sqrt{3}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\frac{-\left(-2\sqrt{2}\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(-2\sqrt{2}\right)^2-4\cdot i\cdot\left(-2\sqrt{3}\right)}}{2\cdot i}$$

Simplify it and you'll get the roots!

Comment: Thanks Jan, You are awesome. but how to simplify the imaginary part?

Comment: @samantha You're more than welcome!

Comment: how to simplify the imaginary part?

Comment: Try to use the polar form

Answer (score 0):

You calculate as for any quadratic equation. First simplify it multiplying it by $-\mathrm i$, and get
$$z^2+2\sqrt2\mathrm i z+2\sqrt3\mathrm i=0.$$
Now the *reduced* discriminant is
$$\Delta'=(\sqrt2\mathrm i)^2-2\sqrt3\mathrm i=-2(1+\mathrm i\sqrt3)=4\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{2\mathrm i\pi}{3}},\quad\text{whence}\quad\sqrt{\Delta'}=\pm2e^{-\tfrac{\mathrm i\pi}{3}},$$
and the resolution formulae yield
$$z=-\sqrt2\mathrm i \pm2e^{-\tfrac{\mathrm i\pi}{3}}.$$
There remains to simplify the results.

Answer (score 0):

Ill continue further on Jan's part.$z=\frac{2\sqrt{2}\pm\sqrt{8+8\sqrt{3}i}}{2i}$ so now we will have to find root of the equation under root.let us assume $\sqrt{8+8\sqrt{3}i}=a+bi$ squaring and comparing real and imaginary part $a^2-b^2=8,2ab=8\sqrt{3}$ so now solving for $a,b$ we get $b=\pm2$ and hence $a=\pm2\sqrt{3}$ so equation becomes $z=\frac{2\sqrt{2}\pm{2\sqrt{3}+2i}}{2i}$ remove out $2$ and multiply and divide by $i$ you get $z=\frac{\sqrt{2}i\pm(\sqrt{3}i-2)}{-1}$ and that are the roots please check my algebra if mistaken but hope you get the method.